# Load app icon from xcassets

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5

I'd like to display the app icon inside my app. The icon is in the default assets catalog (`Images.xcassets`).

How do you load it? I tried the following and they all return `nil`:

```
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon"];
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon"];
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-76"];
image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-60"];
```

Other images in the assets catalog work as expected.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By inspecting the bundle I found that the icon images were renamed as:

```
AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
AppIcon60x60@2x.png
```

And so on.

Thus, using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon76x76"]` or similar works.

Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: There seems to be documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: This is dangerous to do. Apple might change the naming convention and your app break in future. My suggestion is just to copy another icon in your image.xcasset separately.

Comment: is there a method to get the higher resolution images?

Answer (score 18):

I recommend retrieving the icon URL by inspecting the `Info.plist` since there's no guarantee how the Icon files are named:

```
NSDictionary *infoPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSString *icon = [[infoPlist valueForKeyPath:@"CFBundleIcons.CFBundlePrimaryIcon.CFBundleIconFiles"] lastObject];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:icon];
```

In this case we're fetching the last image URL of the CFBundleIconFiles array. It has the largest resolution. Change this if you need a smaller resolution.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. It'd be nice to confirm if the `AppIcon` name is public API or not.

Comment: In my case the icons are named differently. So I wouldn't purely rely on the name.

Comment: why not simply this after having set "icon"? 
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:icon];

Comment: @roberto.buratti you're completely right, it's easier like that. In my special case I actually needed the URL but to create an image it's way easier like that. I've changed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Yossi, much better. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Following Ortwin answer, a **Swift 4** approach:

```
func getHighResolutionAppIconName() -> String? {
    guard let infoPlist = Bundle.main.infoDictionary else { return nil }
    guard let bundleIcons = infoPlist["CFBundleIcons"] as? NSDictionary else { return nil }
    guard let bundlePrimaryIcon = bundleIcons["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as? NSDictionary else { return nil }
    guard let bundleIconFiles = bundlePrimaryIcon["CFBundleIconFiles"] as? NSArray else { return nil }
    guard let appIcon = bundleIconFiles.lastObject as? String else { return nil }
    return appIcon
}
```

Then it can be used like:

```
let imageName = getHighResolutionAppIconName()
myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```