# How To Load The Image Set(The Bundle) From Images.xcasset in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

When I am developing apps in iOS before, I always put the image sources of the app at the root directory of the project, and then I will load them using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]`. I did't even include various sizes and resolutions such as image@2x or image@3x. But I am afraid this is not a good practice, because I cannot deal with different screen resolutions.

Now, I want to make use of the **Images.xcasset** to store all my image sources so that I will be able to load just the bundle name, and hoping that the system will pick the image with the right resolution automatically. Therefore, I made a test and place my image set under **Images.xcasset** and named it as *images*, and then in my UIViewController.m I am trying to load the image by calling **[UIImage imageName:images]**. As a result, it didn't work. So I searched for an answer and found out that I should call `[UIImage imageName:@"images60x60@2x.png"]` in order to load the the 60pt @2x image.

But I think this still did not solve my problem, because I am still choosing which image to load. Is there a way to load the entire image set or load the image according to the resolution of the screen?

Please help. Many Thanks.

EDIT: Added Screen Shots

[image]

I use AppIcon as a test

[image]

Comment: Where did you fond `[UIImage imageName:images60x60@2x]`? That seems so wrong for normal image loading...

Comment: @lukya from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587139/load-app-icon-from-xcassets

Comment: [UIImage imageNamed:images] should work fine as long as you have an image asset by that name.... post the code snippet and a screenshot of your Images.xcasset

Comment: Image assets work same as any other pic in the directory.
[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"] should work.

Comment: @lukya But it states in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587139/load-app-icon-from-xcassets that loading it directly doesn't work, and I also tried it. It really didn't work. You can see he also states that he tried [UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon"]. It didn't work.

Comment: AppIcon stuff can be tricky... try the same for another image and it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said at last that you are using AppIcon as a test. Please don't AppIcon it is made for internal use. try to create you own imageSet and use that. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Two things :

1. As said Ankit, do not use App Icon, use your own set
2. do not use a file suffix. Just reference `[UIImage imageName:@"MyImage"]` (not `[UIImage imageName:@"MyImage.png"]`)